# How do I get firefox to use the windows CA cache

Tags: firefox, trusted-root-certificates

How can I import the windows CA (Certificate Authority) cache/list into firefox or get firefox to use it?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to exists a solution using the tool certutil, see https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/973496.

But i think this is off topic as it imports windows CA into Firefox. I'm not sure you can make Firefox use Windows CA.